# Stored procedure MSSQL to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I need convert this stored procedure mssql to mysql, somebody help me please

1)

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_IS]
as
insert into request (dateIS) values (GETDATE())
```

2)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_RN]
as
select COUNT(id) "quantity" from notify
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

CREATE

```
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]

PROCEDURE sp_name ([proc_parameter[,...]])

[characteristic ...] routine_body

CREATE

[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]

FUNCTION sp_name ([func_parameter[,...]])

RETURNS type

[characteristic ...] routine_body

 proc_parameter:

[ IN | OUT | INOUT ] param_name type

 func_parameter:

param_name type

 type:

Any valid MySQL data type

characteristic:

 COMMENT 'string'

 | LANGUAGE SQL

 | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC

 | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }

 | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }

 routine_body:

Valid SQL routine statement
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modify a Stored Procedure**

MySQL provides an ALTER PROCEDURE statement to modify a routine, but only allows for the ability to change certain characteristics. If you need to alter the body or the parameters, you must drop and recreate the procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_IS;
delimiter //
create PROCEDURE sp_IS 
    BEGIN
      insert into request (dateIS) values (GETDATE())
    END
delimiter;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_RN;
    delimiter //
    create PROCEDURE sp_RN 
        BEGIN
          select COUNT(id) AS quantity from notify
        END
delimiter;
```

Comment: but look this...

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_ingresarSolicitud;
delimiter //
create PROCEDURE sp_IS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO request (dateIS) VALUES (GETDATE());
    END
delimiter;

i have error in the BEGIN, is for this or not? SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO